# Using Finder in Catalina to copy files from my iPad creates duplicate files

Tags: ipad, finder, catalina, file-sharing

I have a folder on my Mac where I keep a manual backup of all files associated with a specific iOS app.  My habit has been to use file sharing to copy the app files (a few hundred) into that folder from time to time as a snapshot.

Before Catalina, doing this with iTunes worked nicely by prompting me to replace existing files.  With Finder and Catalina, I get no prompt and any files that match existing ones in the snapshot folder are copied with a modified file name.  (e.g. File 2.txt for File.txt)

Is there a way to return to previous behavior where existing files are replaced when names match?